# Easy ways or modules to add comments in website

Tags: playframework

I am developing a webapplication with Play scala. My application have comments to be added users.

I am checking if there is any easy way like comments platform kind of module available in play.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such module for Play, anyway you can easily integrate external system into your page ie. [disqus](http://disqus.com/)